# is there a functionality to limit events per cell in agendaWeek view?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to control the number of events per cell in agendaWeek view.
does anyone know how to do it ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `eventLimit` but AFAIK it only works on the all-day slots

Comment: i think this functionality should be add it . it gives more control over the slots

Comment: Ok but don't tell me, tell the people who make fullCalendar. There are some instructions on the fullCalendar website about how to request new features - see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features